# Access mysql get adjacent records using selected row?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have mysql table with the following structure. All records are static and only for read, and had been imported from CSV so all year, month, day are in correct sequence as per I created them. (No, ID column in this table because I only access data by year, month and day)

```
mysql table 'daily'
year month day  data
1990  01    01  xxxxxxxxxxxxx
1990  01    02  eeeeeeeeeeeee
1990  01    03  rrrrrrrrrrrrr
1990  01    04  ttttttttttttt
.
.
.
```

Now, I can access the records by simple select statement as below

```
select * where year=1990 and month=1 and day=03 limit 1
```

But how can I select the query row + 3 or any number of adjacent rows (before or after the query row)? And I don't want to use ID if there is better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using the `DATE` type instead of separate columns for year, month, and day.  Then you can use `DATEADD` and related functions to find the day you want.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to keep them separate because i will find out all records for day=01 with any year or month sometime. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: You can still do that by saying `DAY(mydate)=01`, but it'll do a table scan which will be slower.  If you need day=01 to be fast, you can have both, a date and a day of month field for indexing.

Comment: I understood now. According to your answer, is it possible to specify something like `select * where datecol between begindate and enddate` to select all rows in between the begindate and enddate? And due to the number of records is more than 150,000 and the storage is limited, so i am trying to save the usage. Sorry, one more question, is there any function or trick that I can directly access the selected row + specified number of rows? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the `BETWEEN` syntax you suggest will work.  You can select a single date based on an offset like this: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE datecol=ADDDATE('1990-01-03', 3)`.  Negative offsets are supported as well. `ADDDATE('1990-01-03', -2)`, for example.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate